# Mid Range Website Performance Metrics

Tags: performance

I've been doing a good bit of research into website performance lately and I'd say I've gained a fair amount of knowledge about best practises to improve website performance as well as reduce bandwidth requirements by making such tweaks as GZipping, content caching, and image and script optimization.

My problem is I've found plenty of case studies from hugely popular sites such as Facebook, Google and Amazon but what I really want is some findings and figures for sites a bit smaller say 50-250k visitors a month.

I'm looking for what was gained from investing time into performance optimization e.g. significant speed improvements, reduced bounce rate, reduced running costs, and all the analytics stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook or Google, a 5% performance tuning improvement can save a lot of money. I have done a lot of performance analysis for clients and they often start with tuning questions.  But 90%+ of the time, the greatest performance gain is to look into the application itself.  You cannot tune a tanker to run like a porsche.  This is some findings I found for [Top J2EE Web Application Performance Problems](http://www.jonathanhui.com/top-j2ee-application-performance-problems).  If the web site is using Drupal or Wordpress, you want to turn on the built in caching before going to the production.  Those software package also supply optimization in combining JavaScript and CSS into one file in reducing network round trip time.  If you have a site with a lot of content, increase the memory allocated to different buffers in your DB. For a site with very static content, configure the web server like apache to compress the html data. Set the content expiration policy correctly. Try to optimize the image file size.  I found images in a lot of web site can be further reduced in size without losing much image quality. Make sure the web server have enough physical memory. Most out of the box server configuration is reasonably optimized. So usually there is only a few things need to do. For the type of web site you are looking at, I don't think you need to worry too much.  If you have some files like Flash or PDF that is extremely popular.  You can consider putting those files to CDN (cloud) so have other expertise to take care of the bandwidth for you.  Those solution become pretty affordable even for small and mid site web site now.